# A simple way to reduce \listings indentation

Tags: listings, indentation, verbatim

Is there any simple and easy way to reduce indentation in `\listings`? The default value is too wide to my liking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
breaklines = true,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
<ul>
    <li>bla bla..</li>
    <li>bla bla..</li>
    <li>bla bla..</li>
</ul>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There should be something like `tabsize=2` for the `\lstset`.

Comment: Right. Here a link:http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf p.14(chapter 2.5)

Comment: @TeXnician @Bobyandbob Yes, `\lstset{tabsize=2}` did it. Perfect!

Answer (score 3):

As you have inserted tab characters the solution is to reduce `tabsize` which is a lstlisting option. A value like `2` should make a difference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
breaklines = true,
tabsize=2
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
<ul>
    <li>bla bla..</li>
    <li>bla bla..</li>
    <li>bla bla..</li>
</ul>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```